# My bash terminal is not displaying a full window worth of command lines even in full screen mode

Tags: terminal

My scrollback buffer is not showing as many lines as I would like. How do I get the terminal back to default settings?

I have tried [reset]. 
I have tried bash.

Issuing the `resize` command gives

```
COLUMNS=102; LINES=57;
```

This first image shows my problem.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried running a command *again* that should fill up the terminal?  Or did you resize the window after running a command and were surprised the already-printed output didn't reformat itself?

Comment: What does running resize tell you? What if you eval 'resize' (replace single quotes in that command with backticks)

Comment: `vim` _is_ in the terminal, just like everything else.

Comment: Issuing the resize command gives COLUMNS=102; LINES=57;

Comment: fixed for clarity, please re-open.

Comment: This looks like Ubuntu, is it Ubuntu or a derivative? Which release? Do you have the same problem with another account on the same machine? What happens if you run a full-screen terminal application such as `nano`?

Comment: You deleted one of your screenshots.  That doesn't clarify anything at all.  Your comment about the "resize" command's output should be *in your question,* and also [please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/135943) when you include that information—just include the actual text, correctly formatted.